# Почему вылезает ошибка "group function is not allowed here"?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, select, group-by

Мне требуется вывести всех заказчиков (s.name), с которыми на текущую дату заключено более одного договора (n_dog). В запросе у меня осуществляются проверки на то, является ли дата окончания действия договора (data_finish) больше, чем сегодняшняя дата. Но проблема вот в чём. При исполнении этого кода:

```
SELECT s.name, sd.sid, count(n_dog) FROM subscribers_dogovorov sd
JOIN subscribers s ON sd.sid = s.sid 
WHERE n_dog = (SELECT n_dog FROM subscribers s1
                            WHERE s1.sid = s.sid and
                                  data_finish > SYSDATE) and
count(n_dog) > 1
GROUP BY s.name, sd.sid
ORDER BY s.name;
```

у меня вылезает ошибка:

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

Однако, когда я убираю эту строку:

```
count(n_dog) > 1
```

у меня работает исправно и без ошибок, однако не фильтрует информацию так, как это от меня требуется, ведь по заданию количество договоров должно быть более одного. Если нужна будет более подробная информация о запросе - пишите в комментарии, добавлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае и в Oracle вообще групповые функции могут использоваться либо в списках выбора (SELECT), либо в предложениях ORDER BY и HAVING. Поэтому в данном случае условие

```
count(n_dog) > 1
```

должно быть прописано вместе со словом HAVING. Вот правильный вариант кода:

```
SELECT s.name, sd.sid, count(n_dog) FROM subscribers_dogovorov sd
JOIN subscribers s ON sd.sid = s.sid 
WHERE n_dog = (SELECT n_dog FROM subscribers s1
                            WHERE s1.sid = s.sid and
                                  data_finish > SYSDATE)
HAVING count(n_dog)>1
GROUP BY s.name, sd.sid
ORDER BY s.name;
```

Comment: HAVING должен быть после GROUP BY

Comment: Скажите, как вы проверяете что "правильный вариант кода" действительно правильный?

Comment: Этот код выдаёт мне из таблицы нужные значения. Если это так, то код работает правильно.